# After sync on gitlab code unable to compile and show no error in files but on webpage

Tags: javascript, reactjs, bulma

The error it shows on webpage-
Failed to compile

```
src/pages/Adminstration/IdentityAccess/CreateUserType.jsx
Syntax error: Unexpected token (31:2)

  29 |           <main>
  30 |             <div className="container">
> 31 | <<<<<<< HEAD:src/web/src/pages/Adminstration/IdentityAccess/NewUserType.jsx
       |  ^
  32 |               <Breadcrumb {...{ context: "MANAGE_USERTYPES", leaf: "New User Type" }} />
  33 | =======
  34 |               <Breadcrumb {...{ context: "MANAGE_USER_TYPES", leaf: "new User Types" }} />
```

When I check code in file it is-

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { Header, Sidebar, Breadcrumb } from "../../../components";
import { startLoading, stopLoading } from "../../../components/Util";
import Select from "react-select";

class CreateUserType extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super();
    this.state = {
      loaded: true,
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    document.title = "LIMS - Create User Types ";
  }

  upsert() {
    console.log("TBD....");
  }

  render() {
    !this.state.loaded ? startLoading() : stopLoading();
    return (
      this.state.loaded && (
        <div>
          <Header />
          <Sidebar context="USER_TYPES" />
          <main>
            <div className="container">
            <Breadcrumb {...{ context: "MANAGE_USERTYPES", leaf: "New User Type" }} />
              <h5 className="subtitle is-3">User Type</h5>
              <hr />
```

Someone has changed the filename from NewUserType.js to CreateUserType so I changed the file name everywhere.

Comment: that normally means it conflicts with you local version. You can delete your version and do a `git clone` again. This might be one way. Or you can `git reset` your local version and then pull the latest `git pull`.

Comment: Thanks, It worked. What was the reason behind it?

Comment: Could be anything, ex. you check out a branch which is different than the current version the author is currently committing into. Not really sure :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the product of a failed `git merge`, which is the default strategy Git makes when updating your local repository. If you see this, that means there are conflicts in a file, and it will always be a set format:

The line (or lines) between the lines beginning with `<<<<<<<` and `======` are what you already had in your local copy of the repository (HEAD points to your current branch or commit):

```
> 31 | <<<<<<< HEAD:src/web/src/pages/Adminstration/IdentityAccess/NewUserType.jsx
       |  ^
  32 |               <Breadcrumb {...{ context: "MANAGE_USERTYPES", leaf: "New User Type" }} />
  33 | =======
```

The line (or lines) between the lines beginning with `=======` and `>>>>>>>` are what was pulled from the remote repository (where you `git pull` from) and is different to what Git expects to be in your file:

```
  33 | =======
  34 |               <Breadcrumb {...{ context: "MANAGE_USER_TYPES", leaf: "new User Types" }} />
  35 | >>>>>>>
```

You should pick the one which has the most relevance to your project (or projects) and ensure that you do not have any modified files when you do a `git pull` (google for `git stash` to find out about that)

Comment: Thanks, You described the problem beautifully, It happened because of the failed git merge and some files had conflict.